# javascript countdown timer with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, counter, countdown

i have this code
its make a count down timer in every refresh for page

i need to add cookie take the time and after finish submit form and start time agine

how can i add the code for cookie

```
var time = $('#time').val();
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time + ":" + 00;
startTimer();

function startTimer() {
    var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
    var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
    var m = timeArray[0];
    var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
    if (s == 59) { m = m - 1 }

    if (m == 0 && s == 0) {
        $('#saveQuestion').submit();
    }

    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
        m + ":" + s;

    setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}

function checkSecond(sec) {
    if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) { sec = "0" + sec };
    if (sec < 0) { sec = "59" };
    return sec;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem by adding some more context ?

Comment: could you add your html?

Comment: @Roman why its just span to appear a time

Comment: You're going to find your job is a lot easier if you simply use numeric values for times, like those returned by `Date#getTime()` and `Date.now()`. Calculations are on strictly numeric values, which you can also store in cookies (or wherever), and then you can use those numeric values to render formatted dates into the HTML. Setting cookies via JS is a well-known problem with example code all over, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)